# Ecryptfs automount on startup

Tags: encryption, automount, ecryptfs

i just updated Ubuntu to 22.10 - and after each reboot I have to mount my home files (encrypted with ecryptfs) manually via terminal.

Is there any solution to automate this? Before updating it was automatically mounted..

Thanks a lot!